# SQLAlchemy and adodbapi Database connection error

Tags: sqlalchemy, ironpython, adodbapi

I'm attempting to connect to a mssql SQLExpress 2012 database using sqlalchemy 0.7.8 and adodapi 2.4.2.2 on IronPython 2.7.3

I am able to create a sqlalchemy engine, however when a query is made I get : 
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable"

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 878, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2558, in raw_connection
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 183, in unique_connection
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-0.7.8-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2472, in connect
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Code being used:

```
def conn():
    return adodbapi.connect('Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS; 
                             Initial Catalog=db; User ID=user; Password=pass;')
engine = create_engine('mssql+adodbapi:///', creator=conn, 
                        echo = True, module=adodbapi)
```

adodbapi seems to work fine on it's own, ie. i can create a connection and then use a cursor to query without any problems, it seems to be something in sqlalchemy.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: could you upload you query code as well?

Comment: To make it fail all you need to do is call engine.connect(), It fails before it even gets out to the db

Comment: why dont you try pyodbc instead of adodapi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And we have a workaround:

```
import adodbapi
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool

def connect():
    return adodbapi.connect('Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;\
                         Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=user; Password=pass;')

mypool = pool.QueuePool(connect)
conn = mypool.connect()
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('select 1') #anything that forces open the connection

engine = create_engine('mssql+adodbapi://', module=adodbapi, pool = mypool)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
sess = Session()
```

With this my session object works as normal.

I'm probably not using the adodbapi dialect as intended by whoever made it, but I can't find any documentation, so this is what I've gone with for now.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure adodbapi doesn't work with SQLAlchemy.

[The adodbapi dialect is not implemented for 0.6 at this time.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mssql.html)

Scroll to the very bottom, (this is 0.7x documentation), I also checked 0.8 documentation and it says the same thing.

Sounds like you'll have to change which driver you're using.

Comment: According to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html#supported-databases it is supported, and they have a dialect implemented. I'll have to have a go at debugging it myself, the sqlalchemy support is there, but seems preliminary.

Answer (score 0):

I use sqlalcmy to connect to a postgresql database using the psycopg2. I am not sure, but by reading the documentation, i think you need to download the [pyodbc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/), it seems to be better supported than adodbapi. Once you have installed it, try the following statement to create the engine

```
engine = create_engine(mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@host/db)
```

Or you can check out different ways of writing the connection string [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mssql.html).

Comment: pyodbc unfortunately doesn't work on IronPython, which i'm stuck with due to the unusual nature of the application.

Comment: You're right. Apparently, pyodbc doesn't work with IronPython. Maybe these links should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998558/using-sql-alchemy-and-pyodbc-with-ironpython-2-6-1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455469/ironpython-db-api-2-0